# Confused about handsontable custom editors

Tags: editor, handsontable

I read the wiki on custom editor it shows several methods, createElements, open, prepare, close.
I like to ask and hear from the devs, if I need to use autocomplete from jquery-ui (as it is more configurable), what is the cleanest way to do it?

https://github.com/ratchagarn/handsontable-custom-editor did it with just init and prepare, but it seems to be for an older version of HOT.

Thank you.